# Java - Why is the whitespace being read in as a word?

Tags: java

I am attempting to read in a .txt file and print out the top twenty most common words and the top twenty least common words. However, whitespace appears as a word when it should not be counted as one. As I show in the Output, the whitespace appears as the second most common word, when it should not.
Here is my code.

```
public class WordFreqCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        HashMap<String, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        FileReader bookFile = new FileReader("book.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("book.txt"));


        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            line.trim();
            String[] words = line.split("\\W+");
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i ++) {

                if (frequencyMap.containsKey(words[i])) {
                    frequencyMap.replace(words[i], frequencyMap.get(words[i]) + 1);
                }
                else {
                    frequencyMap.put(words[i], 1);
                }
            }
        }
        s.close();

        List<Entry<String,Integer>> list = sortByValue(frequencyMap);


        System.out.println("Top 20 Most Appeared Words:");

        int counter1 = 1;
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> topTwenty = list.subList(0, 20);
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> word : topTwenty) {
            System.out.println("(" + counter1 + "): " + word.getKey() + " --> " + word.getValue());
            counter1 += 1;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Top 20 Least Appeared Words:");

        int counter2 = 1;
        Collections.reverse(list);
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> bottomTwenty = list.subList(0, 20);
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> word : bottomTwenty) {
            System.out.println("(" + counter2 + "): " + word.getKey() + " --> " + word.getValue());
            counter2 += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Output of my code is

```
(1): the --> 5426
(2):  --> 4986
(3): I --> 3038
(4): and --> 2887
(5): to --> 2788
(6): of --> 2733
(7): a --> 2595
(8): in --> 1747
(9): that --> 1664
(10): was --> 1393
(11): it --> 1303
(12): you --> 1283
(13): he --> 1168
(14): is --> 1131
(15): his --> 1103
(16): have --> 908
(17): my --> 907
(18): with --> 849
(19): had --> 821
(20): as --> 780

Top 20 Least Appeared Words:
(1): rival --> 1
(2): category --> 1
(3): arguments --> 1
(4): Bought --> 1
(5): billycock --> 1
(6): incoherent --> 1
(7): hail --> 1
(8): idle --> 1
(9): illustrious --> 1
(10): terminated --> 1
(11): Apaches --> 1
(12): topped --> 1
(13): laudanum --> 1
(14): filthy --> 1
(15): drama --> 1
(16): tune --> 1
(17): geology --> 1
(18): Mademoiselle --> 1
(19): balls --> 1
(20): Atkinson --> 1
```

It was my understanding that using line.split("\W+") would parse the sentences to make sure nothing like whitespace, commas, etc. were counted in as words or within words. Am I missing something here?

A small portion of book.txt file

===========================================================================

````
almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.net


Title: The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes

Author: Arthur Conan Doyle

Posting Date: April 18, 2011 [EBook #1661]
First Posted: November 29, 2002

Language: English


*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES ***




Produced by an anonymous Project Gutenberg volunteer and Jose Menendez









THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES

by

SIR ARTHUR CONAN DOYLE



   I. A Scandal in Bohemia
  II. The Red-headed League
 III. A Case of Identity
  IV. The Boscombe Valley Mystery
   V. The Five Orange Pips
  VI. The Man with the Twisted Lip
 VII. The Adventure of the Blue Carbuncle
VIII. The Adventure of the Speckled Band
  IX. The Adventure of the Engineer's Thumb
   X. The Adventure of the Noble Bachelor
  XI. The Adventure of the Beryl Coronet
 XII. The Adventure of the Copper Beeches




ADVENTURE I. A SCANDAL IN BOHEMIA

I.

To Sherlock Holmes she is always THE woman. I have seldom heard
him mention her under any other name. In his eyes she eclipses
and predominates the whole of her sex. It was not that he felt
any emotion akin to love for Irene Adler. All emotions, and that
one particularly, were abhorrent to his cold, precise but
admirably balanced mind. He was, I take it, the most perfect
reasoning and observing machine that the world has seen, but as a
lover he would have placed himself in a false position. He never
spoke of the softer passions, save with a gibe and a sneer. They
were admirable things for the observer--excellent for drawing the
veil from men's motives and actions. But for the trained reasoner
to admit such intrusions into his own delicate and finely
adjusted temperament was to introduce a distracting factor which
might throw a doubt upon all his mental results. Grit in a
sensitive instrument, or a crack in one of his own high-power
lenses, would not be more disturbing than a strong emotion in a
nature such as his. And yet there was but one woman to him, and
that woman was the late Irene Adler, of dubious and questionable
memory.

I had seen little of Holmes lately. My marriage had drifted us
away from each other. My own complete happiness, and the
home-centred interests which rise up around the man who first
finds himself master of his own establishment, were sufficient to
absorb all my attention, while Holmes, who loathed every form of
society with his whole Bohemian soul, remained in our lodgings in
Baker Street, buried among his old books, and alternating from
week to week between cocaine and ambition, the drowsiness of the
drug, and the fierce energy of his own keen nature. He was still,
as ever, deeply attracted by the study of crime, and occupied his
immense faculties and extraordinary powers of observation in
following out those clues, and clearing up those mysteries which
had been abandoned as hopeless by the official police. From time
to time I heard some vague account of his doings: of his summons
to Odessa in the case of the Trepoff murder, of his clearing up
of the singular tragedy of the Atkinson brothers at Trincomalee,
and finally of the mission which he had accomplished so
delicately and successfully for the reigning family of Holland.
Beyond these signs of his activity, however, which I merely
shared with all the readers of the daily press, I knew little of
my former friend and companion.```
````

Comment: try to debug and check what value is actually stored, it could be some unicode symbol for non-latin symbol, which cannot be printed in your console

Comment: It's not whitespace that is counted. It's the empty strings.

Comment: Gotcha. I wrote if(words[i].equals("")) {} and it seems to have fixed that so the empty strings are no longer counted. Is there a better way to fix that than this?

Comment: the empty strings @RobbyCornelissen refers to would be between double spaces

Comment: Can you provide with a small sample of your book.txt file?

Comment: @Scratte, I have provided a small sample of the file. I have a fix for this issue as stated in a previous comment but I am still wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the point here is that your're not doing `trim` in fact. This construction

```
line.trim();
```

doesn't actually [trims](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()) a string, it returns a new trimmed one. Strings are immutable in java. You should do something like that

```
String line = s.nextLine().trim();
```

in order to make it work.

Comment: I tried a small test with `String input = "\r\n";` Using `String[] words = input.trim().split("\\W+");` will create the array with one empty string. However omitting the `trim()` creates an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Are there blank lines in the text file? `"".split("\\W+")` will return an array with one blank string element (i.e. `{""}`). Try this at the start of the `while` loop:

```
String line = s.nextLine().trim();
if (line.isEmpty()) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are blank lines in the text file. When I modified my code according to your response, it did not entirely fix the problem. Now instead of being the 2nd most common word, it has fallen to 7th most common word. As I said in an earlier comment, " I wrote if(words[i].equals("")) {}" and put that in the for loop, which fixed the problem. Now my question would be if there is an easier method than that to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

During debugging I found other lines than the blank ones, that gave issues:

- " I. A Scandal in Bohemia.."
- "*** START...".

An `if (words[i].length() == 0) continue;` will be a one size fits all, if placed in the beginning of your `for` loop. However, you can create your words by first removing unwanted characters, then trimming white spaces, and finally replacing unwanted empty lines with a null-terminator:

```
String[] words = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","")  // punctuation
                     .trim()                       // needed as per both issues above
                     .replaceAll("^$","\0")        // terminate the string it it's empty
                     .split("\\W+");
```